netty is giving dns exception for google endpoint api.push.apple.com on java 17
Below error is thrown for the code:
final com.turo.pushy.apns.util.concurrent.PushNotificationFuture<com.turo.pushy.apns.util.SimpleApnsPushNotification, PushNotificationResponse<com.turo.pushy.apns.util.SimpleApnsPushNotification>> sendNotificationFuture = apnsClient.sendNotification(pushNotification);
final PushNotificationResponse<com.turo.pushy.apns.util.SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushNotificationResponse = sendNotificationFuture.get();
io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider - Default DNS servers: [/8.8.8.8:53, /8.8.4.4:53] (Google Public DNS as a fallback)
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] WARN com.turo.pushy.apns.ApnsChannelFactory - Tried to mark promise as "failed," but it was already done.
java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'api.push.apple.com' [A(1)] after 2 queries
Same code is working fine with Java 11 and the dns pointed is io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext - [id: 0x98ee8412] WRITE: UDP, [7752: /10.147.2.10:53], DefaultDnsQuestion(api.push.apple.com. IN A)
When I do nslookup in my machine,nslookup api.push.apple.com
Address:  10.147.2.10
Could anyone please help fix the issue on Java 17 with the above code is pointing to Google's DNS (8.8.8.8)?
